# Searching in code of GitHub repositories

Tags: search, github

How can I search in code of few GitHub repositories within a particular organisation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could do this to search for code in all repositories of a given organization:

`https://github.com/search?q=org%3A<ORG_NAME>+<STRING_TO_SEARCH>&type=Code`

for example:

`https://github.com/search?q=org%3Abroadcom+main&type=Code`

`https://github.com/search?q=org%3Aopenwrt+main&type=Code`

To limit your search to specific repositories press `Advanced Search`
after opening above links and fill in `In these repositories` field.